# Salvar codigo css por via admin

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma função em PHP que vai mostrar-me todo o código CSS no *front end* antes do HTML. Só o admin pode ver esse código CSS imprimido na tela, através do método `"include"`.

O que eu estou a tentar descobrir é como é que posso copiar todo esse CSS apresentado na tela, para um novo ficheiro CSS.

Tendo em conta que esse ficheiro CSSque aparece na tela ele contém variáveis PHP, mas na tela ele não mostra essas variáveis, mas sim o valor delas imprimidas (cores, tamanho de fonte, etc)... ou seja o código de saída apresentado pelo *browser*.

O que eu quero evitar é que o admin tenha que copiar todo esse CSS manualmente através da tela, e o ter que colar num novo ficheiro CSS.

Então agora, eu não sei como conseguir copiar esse CSS que está na tela com alguma função especifica para isso, seja PHP ou Javascript. São cerca de 2000 linhas para serem copiadas para novo ficheiro CSS.

Alguém pode dar-me umas luzes de como posso conseguir isto? Uma vez que o pretendido não é uma função para copiar conteúdo de um ficheiro para outro, com o método *copy*, nesse caso todo o código PHP dentro do CSS seria copiado. O que pretendo é uma maneira de copiar o código de saída apresentado pelo *browser* já com todos os valores do CSS (cores, tamanhos de fonte, etc).

Comment: Se copiar o resultado para a área de transferência já ajuda?

Comment: Essa pergunta me parece estar formulada com um monte de informação que não faz parte do problema, se eu entendi direito. Se não me engano, sua pergunta na verdade é "como salvo o conteúdo de uma variável em um arquivo", corrija-me se eu estiver enganado.

Comment: Acho que ele quer pegar o que está na tela, o css com os valores das variáveis php.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você poderia fazer mais ou menos o seguinte:

```
<?php

    $conteudoProcessado = '* { padding: 0; }';

?>

<form action="salvarArquivo.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="conteudoProcessado" value="<?php echo $conteudoProcessado; ?>" />

    <div>
        <?php echo $conteudoProcessado; ?>
    </div>

    <buttom type="submit"> Salvar </button>
</form>
```

E ai no seu arquivo `salvarArquivo.php` você faz a lógica de salvamento de um arquivo com o conteúdo da variável `$_POST['conteudoProcessado']` e se desejar pode retornar o arquivo salvo para o usuário.

Se quiser que o usuário possa alterar o css gerado pode utilizar uma `textarea` ao invés de um `input hidden` e remover a div com o conteúdo do arquivo.

Comment: O problema é como vou armazenar o código de CSS que está na imprimido na tela para essa variável "$conteúdoProcessado". Mesmo conseguindo isso, estou sem ideias de como posso copiar esse conteúdo da variável para dentro de outro ficheiro, por exemplo: style.css

Comment: Você gera esse CSS dinamicamente correto?

Comment: Sim via admin com nome de ficheiro custom.css

Comment: Como você faz para exibir o conteúdo do arquivo para o usuário admin?

Comment: ele tem o painel de cores com jscolor.js e escolhe as cores que quer para cada tag do html numa página especifica na parte administrativa do site.

Comment: para ele ver o resultado, na <head> tenho a chamada da função desta forma que permite ver todo o CSS antes do HTML:

Comment: <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="custom" href="<?php echo nointernal_css() ?>

Comment: Se ele escolhe as cores, você pode colocar estes campos dentro de um form e fazer com que no submit do form vc crie o arquivo com as configurações definidas pelo usuário

Comment: Tenta alterar a sua pergunta para que fique mais clara a forma que você está fazendo isso, pois se não ficará difícil lhe ajudar

Comment: o form existe, caso contrário não seria possível submeter as modificações pelo usuário admin. Não sei como posso editar de uma forma simples a pergunta inicial.

Comment: Então e se fosse um método para copiar o código fonte, mas apenas o CSS, você nesse caso teria alguma solução? Talvez para uma área de transferência como você referiu, dar um submit e substituir o ficheiro style.css. Você tem algum exemplo funcional que possa colocar aqui? Obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Comment: Tem como você colocar um pouco do código que você utiliza para gerar o css com as opções selecionadas pelo usuário?

Comment: Consegui resolver, obrigado pela sua intervenção :)

Comment: if (isset($_POST['outcss'])) {
   $outcss = $_POST['outcss'];
   $stylecss = fopen('directorio','w');
   fwrite($stylecss, $outcss);
   fclose($stylecss);
}
      <form method="post">
         <textarea name="outcss" readonly="readonly">
   <?php echo nointernal_css() ?>
   </textarea>
         <button>salvar arquivo</button>
      </form>